# How to print (join) 2 loops' result

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have 2 loops:

The first loop:

```
number = 1234567
number_string = str(number)
for ch in number_string:
    print(ch)
```

This will print:

```
1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7
```

I have another loop which is:

```
totalNum = len(str(abs(number)))
for i in range(totalNum, 0, -1):
  print("* 10^ ",int(i-1))
```

and I will get

```
* 10^  6
* 10^  5
* 10^  4
* 10^  3
* 10^  2
* 10^  1
* 10^  0
```

But how do I join these 2 loops to become the result like this:

```
1 * 10^  6
2 * 10^  5
3 * 10^  4
4 * 10^  3
5 * 10^  2
6 * 10^  1
7 * 10^  0
```

I am new to Python, so I couldn't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 4):

How does this work for you:

```
number = 1234567
totalNum = len(str(abs(number)))
for i in range(totalNum, 0, -1):
  print(str(number)[::-1][i-1] + " * 10^ ",int(i-1))
```

Output:

```
1 * 10^  6
2 * 10^  5
3 * 10^  4
4 * 10^  3
5 * 10^  2
6 * 10^  1
7 * 10^  0
```

Answer (score 3):

Several ways to do this, mine uses `enumerate()` to index the string:

```
number = 1234567
number_string = str(number)
totalNum = len(str(abs(number)))

for j,i in enumerate(range(totalNum, 0, -1)):
  print(number_string[j], "* 10^ ", int(i-1))
```

Gives:

```
1 * 10^  6
2 * 10^  5
3 * 10^  4
4 * 10^  3
5 * 10^  2
6 * 10^  1
7 * 10^  0
```

`enumerate()` iterates through a sequence and gives a tuple of the index number (`j`) and the item (`i`).

Comment: @YashidaKimLeeRoger IMO this should be the accepted answer.  It's pythonic, and definitely more efficient than mine at least.

Answer (score 2):

One way, is to store the strings in a list first, then print them:

```
>>> number = 1234567
>>> totalNum = len(str(abs(number)))
>>> string1 = [x for x in str(number)]
>>> string2 = ['* 10^ {}'.format(i-1) for i in range(totalNum, 0, -1)]
>>> for s1, s2 in zip(string1, string2):
...     print(s1, s2)
...
1 * 10^ 6
2 * 10^ 5
3 * 10^ 4
4 * 10^ 3
5 * 10^ 2
6 * 10^ 1
7 * 10^ 0
```

Comment: It worked too! But so far I couldn't understand these line string2 = ['* 10^ {}'.format(i-1) for i in range(totalNum, 0, -1)]
>>> for s in zip(string1, string2):
...     print(' '.join(s)). Could you explain more?

Comment: Take a look at [List comphrehensions](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python). If you have any more doubts, feel free to ask. Also, I've made a small change in the `for` loop. Take a look. I think it's easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

This might help. You can use `zip`

```
number = 1234567
totalNum = len(str(abs(number)))
for v, i in zip(str(number), range(totalNum, 0, -1)):
  print(v, "* 10^ ",int(i-1))
```

**Output:**

```
1 * 10^  6
2 * 10^  5
3 * 10^  4
4 * 10^  3
5 * 10^  2
6 * 10^  1
7 * 10^  0
```